# Attaching a List of Value [LOV] to an existing page item in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm pretty new to APEX ( well, just started using it ~an hour ago), and I'm stuck at a rather basic level.

1. I've created a simple form with all the required fields.
2. I've created a simple LOV.

I can't seem to figure out how to Attach the LOV to the existing item. I tried to attach the LOV by heading over to the item's property and selecting the LOV I created, but it just doesn't seem to attach. Is this a bug with APEX or am I doing something wrong ?

I'm using APEX 4.0 EA 2 [ http://tryapexnow.com ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it - it was under "Display as" attribute. Not sure how I missed it, anyway.
[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/9650/uploadjy.jpg](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/9650/uploadjy.jpg)